# Setting up ASP.NET pages on IIS 6

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, iis-6

I have virtual host where I have set up an IIS 6 server. In the extensions I have added ASP.NET v1.1.4322 and ASP.NET v2.0.50727 and set them to allowed, but I still get a file not found error when using aspx files.

Do I need to setup mimetypes for aspx or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help but you can go to the command line and type:

"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -i"

That may resolve your problem.

Comment: I have hit this issue a million times. aspnet_regiis has solved it about 999,999 of those.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the correct version of ASP.Net in the root website or Virtual DIrectory?